# Is it possbile to SSH in Linux from a 3G USB stick from T-Mobile with Raspberry Pi using a 3G USB stick T-Mobile

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel, 3g

I want to make a SOCKS5 server from Raspberry Pi working on 3G USB modem, and I’m working on Linux from USB modem + VPN/SOCKS. I want to ask you guys, is it possible to do something like that?

T-Mobile is blocking all accessing traffic, so I’m wondering if I can use reverse SSH tunneling?

Will it will work for mobile <-> mobile, without port forwarding?

Or can I forward ports without router?

Is there any solution for this? Is there something simpler? Maybe not SSH?

I found out about Yaler which is a relay infrastructure called that would basically serve as an SSH server between a home machine and the Raspberry Pi. But I don’t know, does it will work with two modems? I’m waiting for account activation now.

Answer (score 1):

Usually mobile networks assign private IPs, which mean that they're not globally routable. Your best bet would be to connect to a VPN you control that allows connections between clients, and then use the internal VPN IPs to connect. Otherwise Yaler does sound like a good alternative

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Tor router for this. Your Rapsberry Pi would be running the SSH server plus a Tor service, and your laptop would be a Tor router client connecting to that service.

Example:

- SSH server runs on Pi and listens on port 22
- Tor router runs on Pi   and exports 127.0.0.1:22 as hidden service (say, abcd.onion)
- Another tor router runs on your laptop and listens on port 9050
- SSH client on your laptop is instructed to use 127.0.0.1:9050 as SOCKS5 proxy and
  to connect to abcd.onion host, with DNS resolution via the proxy

As a result, your SSH client will connect to you server on the Pi without the need to know its IP address.

Of course, Tor is designed for anonymity, not performance, so it's better to use Yaler if you can afford it.